# Accessing previous object in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I get an ActiveRecord object from the console by performing a simple *.last, or other find command.  Is there an easy way to then reference

```
>> u = User.last
=> #<User id: 6, ... >
>> [here!]
```

At [here!] I'd like to type something like %.name or $.name to access the previous object.  Possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's simply `_`

Nothing more, nothing less. Works in all irb consoles save for Heroku's.